# Is there any way to get buffer size in bytes?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

I'm studying network in college.
I want to know buffer size of Youtube live streaming.
If I use statistics I can only get buffer size in seconds, but I want to get this buffer size in bytes.

I tried to calculate streaming rate(in bytes) multiple with buffer size(In seconds), but it doesn't show me accurate buffer size.

Is there any way to get accurate buffer size of live streaming in bytes?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Havent personally tried this yet. Youtube has a deprecated function namely [getVideoBytesLoaded()](https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference#getVideoStartBytes()) which returns the number of bytes loaded for the current video. It's now been [replaced with getVideoLoadedFraction()](https://youtube-eng.googleblog.com/2012/07/know-whats-loaded_24.html).